# TDD on Android with Robolectric and Mockito

Tags: android, tdd, mockito, robolectric

Do you know any course or book, free or not, that teaches TDD in Android with technologies like Robolectric or Mockito?

Comment: Mmm. I would recommend to get good course with TDD with junit (with Mockito and AssertJ for example). nd practice android tests with Robolectric yourself. I don't think Robolectric TDD course ever exists

Comment: @EugenMartynov It does! See the accepted answer. :)

Comment: You don't really need robolectric in 2016. TDD is taught in this book as well as other idea's around testing https://www.amazon.co.uk/Learning-Android-Application-Testing-Blundell/dp/1784395331 shameless self plug

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for the mention Corey D! Like other Corey said, I have a few things available that teach TDD with Robolectric.

- [CasterIO video series](https://caster.io/courses/robolectric/) which starts out with integrating the tool and shows you how to test many different things in the Android space. This is the resource that's being updated most often right now.
- [Android Activity Book](http://gumroad.com/l/androidactivitybook) covers writing a Calculator app from scratch with TDD.
- The [Intro to Android Katas](https://gumroad.com/l/androidkataintro) video series gives step by step instructions for my [kata workshop](http://coreylatislaw.com/robolectric-kata/).

If you're new to Android development, the [Android Theory Book](http://gumroad.com/l/androidtheorybook) that covers Android fundamentals and Android Studio Basics.

[Chiu-Ki Chan](http://blog.sqisland.com/) is creating Espresso tutorials on her blog and just released her first [video series](https://gumroad.com/l/AndroidTestSharedPref).

Comment: any discount when buying both books? :P

Comment: @Ewoks There's a bundle that has both books and and the videos and is cheaper than buying both books together: gum.co/androidtddbundle.

Comment: Also I have a code "yearoftdd" that still has some mileage left on it for $5 on each book/video download individually.

Comment: make sense to test with Roboelectric today? I heard a lot of criticism about the fact that is not going to real test

Answer (score 3):

I have not gone through it myself, but [Corey Latislaw](http://coreylatislaw.com/) has put together [a couple eBooks on Android Development](http://coreylatislaw.com/android-activity-book/) and specifically a [Robolectric Kata](http://coreylatislaw.com/robolectric-kata/) that walks through building a sample application.